# Why does Google Cloud Compute Engine IP differ from the static one I have reserved?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell, static-ip-address

I have set a static IP address for my Google Cloud Compute Engine. When I go to the network details of the engine, it tells it is 34.88.xx.xx

However - when I now run a test python script in the cloud shell, it tells me that the requests comes from an IP that is 34.91.xx.xx

It looks like I should not run the script on the Shell but somehow run it in the compute engine. Hard to figure out how that could be done.

Comment: More details are required regarding your configuration.

Comment: Either you have not attached the static IP to your VM or you are just getting data from cloudshell and not your actual VM

Comment: You are right. It is cloudshell I use for running it. I wonder how I could run it on the actual vm

Comment: Log in with ssh in your VM and run your script in it!

Comment: From cloudshell, use this command [gcloud compute ssh VMname](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) or click the SSH button at MENU>COMPUTE ENGINE

Answer (score 1):

As @Dany L suggested, if you want to run a python script on a VM you need to SSH to the VM. You can connect to VM instances through the Google Cloud Console or the gcloud command-line tool. After you connect, use the terminal to run commands on your VM instance.

Refer [Connecting to VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#connecting_to_vms) and [gcloud command ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh).